# How do I update mutiple rows of a table using Cursor loop?

Tags: mysql, database-cursor

I have 3 database located in different schema, lets call it

- `source_schema.target_table`
- `target_A.target_table`
- `target_B.target_table`

and wanted to move data from table `source_schema` to `target_A`, `target_B`.

Data in `source_schema` is judged by `source_schema.target_table.target_column` using a stored function that return the schema target (A or B).

I tried copying only the `id` and `target_col_val` into a new table, and run loop through it, and delete the top rows of the new table as the process ended, but I'm worried about performance, so I gave up on this solution since it require lots of `SELECT` and `DELETE`.

Right now this is what I have:

```
DECLARE target_schema VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE target_col_val VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE target_column VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE tempid VARCHAR(100);

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, target_column FROM A.target_table INTO tempid, target_col_val;
OPEN cur;

curloop: LOOP
DO

-- THIS PART OF THE CURSOR LOOP LOGIC
-- FECTH(?)

SET target_schema = get_target_schema(target_table, target_column, target_col_val)


-- UPSERT
INSERT INTO target_schema.target_table (id, name, etc)
SELECT id, name, etc FROM A
WHERE id = tempid;

END LOOP;
```

Comment: You cannot use local variables values as objects names in the query. Use dynamic SQL (PREPARE statement). PS. Object name length cannot exceed 64 octets, so VARCHAR(100) is excess.

Comment: Alternatively to dynamic sql, if you only have 3 target tables, you can also just use "if" and 3 inserts, one for each condition.

Comment: Also note that in 98% of cases where someone does something with a cursor, it can and should be done without a cursor. Your case (as described) can probably be done with a "insert into A.target_table (id, name, etc) select id, name, etc from A.source_table where get_target_schema(target_table, target_column, target_col_val) = 'A'." (repeat 2 more times for "B.target_table" and "='B'" and so on). So you might want to add your actual problem, so we could check if it can be simplified from your *"lots of SELECT and DELETE"*.

Comment: Thank you for your input. For now I will try using the `IF` insert, with a prepared statement. Will update the question again later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of thinking, I reached to this answer and it works like a charm.
Hopefully this can help anyone with same problem

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure()
BEGIN

DECLARE target_schema VARCHAR(64);
DECLARE target_column_value VARCHAR(64);
DECLARE temp_table_id VARCHAR(18);
DECLARE fetch_done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

-- Declaring the cursor
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, target_column FROM target_schema.target_table;
-- Setting the end 
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fetch_done = TRUE;

-- prepare a template upsert statement
SET @upsert_statement_template = 
    'INSERT INTO $$distribution_schema$$.target_table 
        (id, name, etc)
    SELECT 
        id, name, etc
    FROM 
        source_schema.target_table AS internaltb 
    WHERE 
        internaltb.id = ?
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        name = internaltb.name, etc = internaltb.etc;';

OPEN table_cursor;

-- cursor loop
TableCursorLoop: LOOP
    FETCH table_cursor INTO temp_table_id, target_column_value;

    -- ending the loop when all the rows are fetched
    IF fetch_done THEN
        LEAVE TableCursorLoop;
    END IF;

    -- get the target schema
    SET @target_schema = get_target_schema('passing the parameter to funtion');
    SET @temp_table_id = temp_table_id;
    
    -- prepare the upsert statement using the template
    SET @upsert_statement = REPLACE(@upsert_statement_base, "$$distribution_schema$$", @distribution_schema);

    -- execute the upsert statement
    PREPARE stmt FROM @upsert_statement;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @temp_table_id;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END LOOP;
CLOSE table_cursor;

END
```